# How do I create a Bode plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

I have calculated a transfer function for a specific system (a low pass filter):

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{RCj\omega +1}$$

It seems to me that the standard way of plotting the frequency response of the filter is to use a Bode plot. Therefore I want to know how to do that in Matlab.

There is a function bodeplot in Matlab which for instance takes an argument calculated with `tf`, which in turn takes a numerator and denominator.

I don't actually understand how I should use those functions with my already calculated formula above. Have I already calculated some part which could be done with the above mentioned Matlab functions?

So, how do I make a Bode plot from my transfer function, in Matlab?

Here is my current Matlab plot, which plots the frequency response (but not with dB on the y-scale):

```
f = 0:100000;
R = 33e3;
C = 220e-12;

w = 2*pi*f;

H_w = 1./(R.*C.*j.*w+1);

xaxis = 0:100000;

figure;
semilogx(xaxis,abs(H_w));
```

Comment: I don't know matlab, but a bode plot is on a log - log scale.  Log of the amplitude response vs log of the frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `tf` with vectors of the coefficients for the numerator and denominator (ordered from highest power to lowest):

`H = tf([1],[RC 1]);`

where `RC` is your \$RC\$ time constant.

Then call `bode(H)`.

See the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bode.html) (especially the examples).

Comment: This works if you have the signals toolbox.  It's more of a todo if you dont.